# Map implementation - Code smell in Lookup() & Insert()

Tags: go

Below code is Map implementation using array, slice & pointers:

```
package gomap

import "fmt"

type Entry struct {
    stockName  string
    stockValue float64
}

type bucket []Entry

type Map [4]bucket

type bucketElementPosition [4]int

var emptyPosition = bucketElementPosition{0, 0, 0, 0}

func Newmap() Map {

    return Map{} // [(nil,0,0), (nil,0,0), (nil,0,0), (nil,0,0)]
}

func (m *Map) Lookup(key string) float64 {

    bucketNumber := (key[0] - 'A') / 7
    for _, entry := range m[bucketNumber] { // (*m)[bucketNumber]
        if entry.stockName == key {
            return entry.stockValue
        }
    }
    return 0
}

func (m *Map) Insert(key string, value float64) {

    bucketNumber := (key[0] - 'A') / 7

    if cap(m[bucketNumber]) == 0 { // (*m)[bucketNumber]
        fmt.Println("bucket number:", bucketNumber)
        m[bucketNumber] = make([]Entry, 0, 100)
    }

    m[bucketNumber] = append(m[bucketNumber], Entry{key, value})
    emptyPosition[bucketNumber]++
}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/myhub/cs61a/gomap"
)

func main() {

    var stockData = gomap.Newmap()


    (&stockData).Insert("AAPL", 94.56)
    (&stockData).Insert("HSCO", 26.72)
    (&stockData).Insert("NMZN", 697.45)
    (&stockData).Insert("ZSFT", 50.81)
    (&stockData).Insert("PMGN", 150.83)

    fmt.Println((&stockData).Lookup("AAPL"))
    fmt.Println((&stockData).Lookup("HSCO"))
    fmt.Println((&stockData).Lookup("NMZN"))
    fmt.Println((&stockData).Lookup("ZSFT"))
    fmt.Println((&stockData).Lookup("PMGN"))

}
```

---

Code smell `bucketNumber := (key[0] - 'A') / 7` can be taken care by reading bits and hash.

but for line     `type bucket []Entry`

How to make the concrete type `Map`, `Entry` type agnostic? because key is fixed as `string` and value is fixed as `float64`

Answer (score 2):

I completed the home assignment like this:

```
package gomap

import "fmt"

type Entry struct {
    key, value interface{}
}

type Map struct {
    buckets [4][]Entry
}

func Newmap() *Map {
    return &Map{}
}

func (m *Map) bucketNumber(key interface{}) int {
    s := fmt.Sprint(key)
    return int(s[0]) % len(m.buckets)
}

func (m *Map) Lookup(key interface{}) interface{} {
    bucketNumber := m.bucketNumber(key)
    for _, entry := range m.buckets[bucketNumber] {
        if entry.key == key {
            return entry.value
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (m *Map) Insert(key interface{}, value interface{}) {
    bucketNumber := m.bucketNumber(key)
    m.buckets[bucketNumber] = append(m.buckets[bucketNumber], Entry{key, value})
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KmVSeDavc3y

Comment: `s := fmt.Sprint(key)` would always expect keys to be string only.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do that. The most obvious is to use interface{} for key and value. However, there's a type-safe way of doing the keys. You can make `Key` an interface:

```
type Key interface {
   // Returns the bucket number for the key
   BucketNumber() int
   // Eq compares the key with the given key
   Eq(Key) bool
}
```

Then you can have an Entry using this key:

```
type Entry struct {
    k Key
    v interface{}
}
```

You can rewrite the map functions to use this key. Value would have to be an interface, and you have to use type assertions to get the underlying value.

Comment: **1)** Are you asking the API user to implement the `BucketNumber()` by introducing `BucketNumber()` api as part of interface? Because API is `func (m *Map) Lookup(key interface{}) interface{} {//...}`  and  `func (m *Map) Insert(key interface{}, value interface{}) {//.....}`.  **2)** `BucketNumber()` cannot be exported...because this is implementation detail

Comment: 1) Yes, and of course, that requires a change to the Lookup and Insert functions. 2) Note that this is a copy of the Java object system where all objects have a hashCode() and equals() methods

Comment: When you say, "you have to use type assertions to get the underlying value.", You mean using type assertion in the user code?

Comment: Yes, Lookup() returns an interface{}, the caller has to do a type assertion to get the value with the correct type.